Remove common company name suffixes in Python using regex
I'm struggling to remove suffixes from some company names. The expected result is like below:
Original Names:
Apple Inc.
Sony Corporation
Fiat Chrysler Automobiles S.p.A.
Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.

Cleared Names:
Apple
Sony
Fiat Chrysler Automobiles
Samsung Electronics

What I have done until now:
import re

def remove_company_suffixes(company_name):
  suffix_pattern = r"\s*(?:co(?:rp(?:oration)?|mpany)?|ltd\.|llc|gmbh|sa|sp\.a\.|s\.r\.l\.|ag|nv|bv|inc\.|s\.a\.s\.|e\.u\.|s\.l\.|s\.a\.l\.|doo|dooel|d.o.o.|szr|ltd|inc|llc|corp|ag|sa|sp|sl)\.?$"
  return re.sub(suffix_pattern, '', company_name.strip())

company_names = ["Apple Inc.", "Sony Corporation", "Fiat Chrysler Automobiles S.p.A.", "Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.", "Plasticos SA", "ABC GmbH"]
for company_name in company_names:
  cleaned_name = remove_company_suffixes(company_name)
  print(cleaned_name)

The result is:
Apple
Sony
Fiat Chrysler Automobiles S.p.A.
Samsung Electronics Co.,
Plasticos
ABC


i don't think regex is the best tool here: you're not searching for a pattern, it's not working and you're turning your code maintenance into a living hell

llc, ag, sa are all repeated

@folengateis I'm agree with you, regex could not work perfectly here

Have you considered just constructing a list of known suffixes then split the strings and remove the last component if it's found in your list of suffixes

What about "The Coca-Cola Company"?

It looks like you're getting case-sensitive results, so make sure you pass in flags = re.IGNORECASE into the re.sub method, and you also have a typo in S.p.A in your pattern where you're missing the first period (you have sp.a instead of s.p.a). This only leaves the problem of Samsung where there's two company suffixes. I'm not sure how to deal with this, maybe just run it through your filter multiple times and account for trailing commas too.


Hope that helps.

The obvious fix is to add a + at the end to replace one or more repetitions. I would also make the periods optional, since you frequently see these abbreviations with or without periods and commas.
def remove_company_suffixes(company_name: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(
    r"(?:,?\s*(Corp(?:\.|oration)?|S\.?p\.?A\.?|Inc\.?|Co\.?|Ltd\.?|etc))+$",
    "",
    company_name.strip(),
    re.IGNORECASE)

I'll leave it to you to articulate the whole regex; the above includes just the main abbreviations for your examples.

You need to first identify precisely the rule to be applied to obtain the result you want. The required regex often will follow easily. One possibility is to enumerate the possible suffixes to be removed, as is done in other answers.
Another is "remove all substrings at the end of the string that begin with one or more spaces followed by: a) 'corporation', 'sa' or 'gmbh' (case independent) followed by a word boundary; or b) one or more letters (case independent) followed by a period, where a) or b) is followed by zero or more characters other than line terminators". There may of course be suffixes that do not contain a period other than "corporation", "sa" and "gmbh" that need to be included.
The idea of this assumption is that the substring to be kept will contain no periods and if "corporation", "sa", "ga" or a period is present all characters in the tail of the string as specified above are to be removed. If this rule is correct (I don't know if it is) one may convert a match of the following regular expression (with flags=re.IGNORECASE) to an empty string:
 +(?:corporation\b|sa\b|gmbh\b|[a-z]+\.).*

Note the first character of this expression is a space.
Python demo <-\(ツ)/-> Regex demo
The expression can be broken down as follows.
  +               # match one or more spaces
 (?:              # begin a non-capture group 
   corporation\b  # match 'Corporation' followed by a word boundary
 |                # or
   sa\b           # match 'sa' followed by a word boundary
 |                # or
   gmbh\b         # match 'gmbh' followed by a word boundary
 |                # or
   [a-z]+         # match one or more letters
   \.             # match a period
 )                # end non-capture group
 .*               # match zero or more characters other than line terminators

